# iOS: Changing TabBarItem of not selected tab

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a TabBar Controller with two ViewControllers (A and B) and would like to change the font size of the two Tab Bar Items. When the first tab A ViewController is loaded, I can change the tab item font size using [self tabBarItem] setTitleTextAttribute.

However, how would I reference the tab bar item of the ViewController B from A so I can change the font as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reference to the other viewController(s) through self.tabbarController.viewControllers

Answer (score 0):

You can add a singleton: [Shared Instances](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)for the UITabBar and get the single reference or you can create a class that has two UIViewControllers and their accompanying UITabBars and just call them as class variables. I don't really like singletons but it boils down to preference and data model of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Like @andershqst stated `self.tabbarController.viewControllers`. I maintain an enum for my tabs.

```
typedef enum SICOTabIndexes {
    kSICOTabIndexHome,
    kSICOTabIndexSaved,
    kSICOTabIndexCamera,
    kSICOTabIndexList,
    kSICOTabIndexSettings
} SICOTabIndexes;
```

I then can use `controller.tabBarController.viewControllers[kSICOTabIndexHome]` to get a particular view controller.

```
UIViewController *homeController = controller.tabBarController.viewControllers[kSICOTabIndexHome]
```

At that point, use `homeController.tabBarItem` to make the changes you need.